# how to get hard disk information in c?

Tags: c, windows, hard-drive

I am using MSVS 2008.  I am writing an application in c, and would like to know whats the best way to determine hard disk information such as space available and total capacity.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Win32 API reference is where you should be looking.

The call for free space is [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937(VS.85).aspx)